# How can deceleration due to friction be positive?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, friction, free-body-diagram

If an object on a rough plane moves from A to B with negative acceleration -8m/s/s (due to friction). And back from B to A on that same surface, why is the acceleration then changed to positive? In fact, friction slows things down so it should be negative as well. Could you explain in detail how it is that the sign changes.

Comment: In your scenario, by what mechanism does the object go back from B to A? You need to provide more details on what is going on from A to B and back..

Comment: Kindly consider providing full information

Comment: well it just has velocity in the AB direction along with muR due to friction acting in the opposite direction

Comment: @sweetiesakura I've noticed in your comments to answers below that you are unfamiliar with very basic physics notation ($\hat{i}$) and expressions (FBD in context with acceleration). Are you trying to learn physics on your own? telling us your physics background helps structure answers better.

Comment: actually, i'm doing maths not physics, but i thought that this type of question would be more appropriate on the physics stack exchange.

Comment: @sweetiesakura You only described the motion from A to B. But you have not told us how the object gets back to A.

Comment: it hits a wall , loses some of its kinetic energy, and goes back with a reduced velocity magnitude.

Answer (score 2):

We really need to see your FBD and equations for this because the issue is you are either not being consistent in your FBDs when you assign polarities to the directions of the vectors or you are being consistent but don't understand it.

Nothing says the force you exert has to be positive. Nothing says friction has to be negative. Positive and negative are just math conventions. Positive and negative are arbitrary. All that is required is that they are opposite. The math is dumb and has no context to the problem. It just knows positive and negative are opposite and it is up to you to assign meaning to them. And you have to be consistent since the math has to be consistent.

For a falling object problem, I could define everything pointing down as negative and everything pointing up as positive. Or I could do the opposite and define everything pointing up as negative and everything down as positive. It doesn't matter as long as I am consistent.

If your pushing force was to the right, you could define everything pointing right as positive and everything right as negative. Since friction would be opposite of your pushing force then friction would be negative. But you could also do the opposite. You could define left as positive and right as negative. In that case the pushing force would be negative and the friction force would be positive. Does it matter? No, it doesn't. What matters is the friction and pushing are opposite of each other.

The math only cares about consistency.

In fact, in some problems you don't actually know what direction a force points ahead of time. So you have to "guess" by just assigning it a direction and therefore a polarity based on your convention and working the problem out. And if the *number* you calculate is positive it means that you guessed correctly. But if the number is negative then that means you guessed incorrectly and it is actually in the opposite direction of what you guessed.

---

For example:

If my convention is

- Down = positive
- Up = negative

The usual convention is up is positive and down is negative but I chose a convention that is unusual on purpose to prove the point that it doesn't matter and to try and break you out of rigid thinking if you happen to be stuck in it.

Let's say I have a block supported on a table with weight of m. I know there's the acceleration of gravity pulling the weight down. We intuitively know that the table has to exert a force up to stop the block from falling.

$\Sigma F = ma$

$(mg) - (N) = m(0\frac{m}{s^2})$

When the forces are on the same side of the equal sign, everything in one direction has one sign and the everything in the opposite direction has the opposite sign based on our sign convention. The same holds true for the acceleration terms (the 'ma' terms but there is only one in this problem).

If we calculate the above out, we get:

$N = mg$

Great. We guessed correctly because our N is positive.

---

But let's pretend we DO NOT know that the normal force will ultimately point up to opposite gravity. In that case, we have to guess the direction and calculate things out. The math will give us the magnitude of the force and the sign will tell us whether we guessed the correct direction or not.

$\Sigma F = ma$

$(mg) + (N) = m(0\frac{m}{s^2})$

Like before, we assigned positive to the mg term since it is down and in our sign convention down is postive. And we guessed (wrong on purpose) that the normal force will also be down so it is positive too.

If we solve the equation, we get:

$N = -mg$

Notice that the number we get for N is negative. That means the direction is the OPPOSITE of what we guessed. So the magnitude is correct but the direction is the opposite because we guessed wrong.

If we take our result and plug it back into the original equation we get:

$(mg) + (N) = m(0\frac{m}{s^2})$

$(mg) + (-mg) = m(0\frac{m}{s^2})$

$(mg) - (|N|) = m(0\frac{m}{s^2})$

This is identical to the equation we had when we guessed the direction of the normal force correct:

$(mg) - (N) = m(0\frac{m}{s^2})$

$(mg) - (|N|) = m(0\frac{m}{s^2})$

If we had guessed correct, our calculated N would have been positive and not changed anything in the equation (hence the absolute sign just to try and make things clearer). Our result always gives us the correct magnitude but the sign tells us whether we guessed our direction correctly or not because when you fit the entire number into the original equation, the sign on the number will change the sign on the term in the equation if the number is negative.

So you can see whether something is positive or negative doesn't actually matter. What matters is whether they are opposite or not because the math only knows if something is opposite or not. It's stupid. It has no context to the problem. You're the one who has to assign meaning to positive or negative and it doesn't matter which you pick as long as you are consistent because the math must be consistent.

Comment: well, your explanation is consistent. thats for sure.

Comment: what did you mean by FBD btw?

Comment: @sweetiesakura FBD means free body diagram. You need those and not using those is a common reason why people get conventions mixed up. This is the kind of thing that happens when you don't: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/632735/why-is-it-incorrect-to-to-add-accelerations-when-something-is-accelerating-downw/632752#632752

Comment: i saw on yahoo that free body diagrams are those pictures drawn when solving a mechanics problem. Could you tell me why is the name ''free body diagram''? Is the body ''free'' because there are no external forces acting on it ?  (for example, tension...)

Comment: @sweetiesakura Well it's called a free body diagram because the you draw the body of interest "freed" from the stuff around it (like mechanical attachments etc). And the forces you draw on the diagram are the forces being **exerted on the body only**. You *do not draw the forces that the body is exerting*. In the link above, you draw the diagram like how I did with it mirroring the F=ma equation (or rotation equivalent $\tau=I\omega$)

Comment: By body of interest, I mean whatever section of whatever thing you are interested in. If you are interested in the car, you draw the car. If you are interested in just the wheel on the car, you draw the wheel "freed" from the car. If you are interested in the inner stress of a rope segment that is part of a larger rope, you cut up the rope segment.

Comment: but as weight is exerted by the object, we do not draw the weight vector then?

Comment: @sweetiesakura That's not correct thinking. This is why you need a FBD. You are confusing what forces are being exerted on what and confusing your perspective with the block's perspective. Weight is a force exerted *by the planet* on the object. If the object is sitting in your hand, then your hand *also* exerts a normal force in the opposite direction on the object to support it. Both of these forces are being exerted on the object so they are in its FBD.

Comment: However if you draw a FBD of your hand, then the the weight of the object is exerting a force on your hand downard which is equal and opposite to the upward "normal" force in the FBD for the object. Can you see the difference? Do not confuse the force being exerted on your hand for the force being exerted on the object.

Comment: Another example is a rocket. A rocket doesn't have inertia less propulsion. It doesn't apply a forward force to itself to move forward. It exerts a force on the thrust exhaust cloud and throws out it out backward. The FBD for the thrust cloud being expelled has a force exerted backwards on it by the rocket. Due to equal and opposite reaction, if you draw the FBD for the rocket, there is a forward force being exerted on the rocket by the thrust.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about components of motion in a 1D system (as along an x axis). There must be a choice for the positive direction. An object moving in the positive direction has a positive velocity. An object loosing speed while moving in the negative direction has a positive acceleration. (If continued, it will eventually stop and then gain speed in the positive direction.)

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea of acceleration being negative is false. Acceleration is a vector quantity, it has direction and magnitude. A vector's magnitude cannot be negative, $|\vec{a}| \ge 0$ and direction is not something you can specify as negative or positive. If the aforementioned acceleration vector is 1-dimensional it can be written as:

$$
\vec{a} = |\vec{a}|\hat{i}
$$

The most you can say about this is that if it points through the negative direction or the positive direction.

If the net force (friction in your case) independent of time let's say:

$$
\vec{F}_{fr} = \langle -3 \rangle
$$

Since $ \vec{F}_{net} = m\vec{a} $:

$$
\frac{1}{m}\langle -3 \rangle = \vec{a}
$$

We know that mass is scalar and positive so the acceleration vector can point through to the negative direction if the net force vector points through to the negative direction.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124751/discussion-on-answer-by-explorer-how-can-deceleration-due-to-friction-be-positiv).

Answer (score 0):

> And back from B to A on that same surface, why is the acceleration
> then changed to positive? In fact, friction slows things down so it
> should be negative as well.

Kinetic friction always slows things down. But static friction can both slow things down and speed things up (cause acceleration) depending on the circumstances. I'm not sure how that would apply to your scenario because you have not provided sufficient details.

For a car it is static friction between the drive wheels and the road that causes a car to accelerate.  See the Fig below. Per Newton's third law the static friction force acting forward on the drive wheel is equal and opposite to the force the drive wheel exerts on the road. Then, since the static friction force is the only external force acting on the car (ignoring air resistance) per Newtons second law the static friction force equals the mass of the car times its acceleration.

On the other hand, either static or kinetic friction can cause the car to decelerate depending on whether or not skidding occurs during braking. But only static friction can cause acceleration.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Kinetic friction doesn't always slow things down. Consider a mass resting on a smooth cloth, all resting on a table. The cloth is pulled quickly, causing the mass to move in the direction of the pull, but not with the same instantaneous velocity as the cloth. It gained speed, moving forward relative to the table and backwards (measured bythe same coordinate directions) relative to the cloth. But it went from rest to not-at-rest, and the force was kinetic friction.

Comment: @BillN Hmm, perhaps. But it seems to me that it was static friction that initially caused the mass to move in the direction of the pull before the friction became kinetic.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to your axes.

- If the axis points from A to B, then with positive velocity, friction causes opposite, thus negative, acceleration.
- With negative velocity (we are moving backwards from B to A) friction pulls backwards, meaning in the positive direction, so the acceleration is positive.

The signs might relate to an axis direction like this and not to other properties.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple question to understand. Let us say you have your car and putting it in the reverse gear and going back. Friction will act in forward direction. Now , you slowly try to increase the acceleration of your car. Then , deceleration will tend to decrease and then become positive after some time. After acceleration is positive  now , friction direction will also change.

Check on direction of friction online if you have difficulty.

Therefore , it is all a matter of Cartesian coordinates you choose.